# extract and replace pixel color from pdf document on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, image-processing

is there a way to extract the present pixel color from the pdf document and then change the color according to conditions.

For example, if i have to implement night mode (black background and white text) on a pdf document, can we do something like, if the color of the pixel is white then make it black and vice versa.

For iOS.